# python-mode plugin breaks gVim

Tags: python, windows, vim

I had a perfectly running customized gVim copy on my Windows XP machine. But for an unknown reason, the program isn't running now, whenever I lunch it, it immediately closes the process.

After trying to disable each plugin, I realized that klen-python-mode (that runs as a bundle via pathogen) is the source of the problem.

Edit: ipy.vim plugin used to work too, but it's keeping Vim from running too.
Any tips how to solve that? Or the cause of the issue to begin with?

Comment: Do these plugins require vim to be compiled with +python?  Did you, maybe, upgrade your system's python?

Comment: If you upgraded python then you need to rebuild vim against the new python.  As to how to do that on Windows, I have no idea.  See if there is a binary out there with support for the python version you're running.

Comment: I don't really bild Vim myself. I use the ready build here:
http://tuxproject.de.nyud.net/projects/vim/
And I tried downloading and using the newest build they have.

Comment: Is any output produced by gvim when you run it from command-line?